# How can I access my Mosquitto Broker hosted on EC2 instance?

Tags: mosquitto

I have installed Mosquitto broker on EC2 instance but the mqtt client cannot access the broker.

What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Likely you need to add the MQTT port 1883 (or 8883) to your security group to allow access from external client.